# How can I do a diff between two webpages with Beautiful Soup

Tags: beautifulsoup

How can I do a diff between two different webpages with Beautiful Soup? Ideally I'd like the diff to report in a smart way how the DOM changed, and not worry about insignificant whitespace, etc. This is why I was looking at Beautiful Soup.

Comment: There can be many approaches to do this. one is analyze the tag that you want check for changes.